# Use image magick to composite images

Tags: ipad, imagemagick, screenshot

I have a raw iPad screenshot and I would like to place a "perfect battery top bar" top on it. I believe I can use `$ composite -gravity` to accomplish this, but I am new to imagemagick and its massive library... any tips on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use composite and check that the topbar has the same width as the image. In composite parameter 3 + 4, are the x and y offset. Since you want it aligned on top, use 0, 0.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$topbar = new Imagick("/var/www/topbar.png"); //600*19px
$tapir = new Imagick("/var/www/tapir.jpg"); // 600*400px

$tapir->compositeImage($topbar, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
echo $tapir;
?>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That'll do it, thanks Lukas! I ended up using something a little different as I need it to run through an array of images. Thanks!